# Regex Notepad ++ www and com

Tags: regex, notepad++

how to change fast text in notepad ++

i have 13k lines of text with domain names example:

```
www.domain
domain.com
nextone.com
www.domain.com
```

i want remove all of them strings what have www. and .com

Comment: So, a good start. What have you tried so far? What is the expected result for the current output?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general how-to-use-software tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a copy of your file.
2. Use Find what: with RegEx `www\..+\.com`
3. Use Replace with nothing combined with Replace All to delete all lines having www. and .com

or if you mean delete all substrings www. and/or .com in a line then use it in a similar way.

[image]